# Why is my address bar in safari doing this?

Tags: mac, safari, macos

Randomly my safari just started doing this:
[image]

I tried recreating the `com.apple.Safari.plist` file but nothing changed. Whats up with this?

Comment: Servers were borked yesterday. Was a world wide issue

Comment: You say it "was" does this mean it's fixed because I still have the issue.

Comment: It hit all the newspapers yesterday, the same links are now saying it's fixed.

Comment: @Tetsujin I still have the issue so it's not fixed.

Comment: Have you rebooted your computer & router?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, multiple times. I don't see how this would even be an internet problem.